getting unable to find elemen in jest
Am using react native , and am having a component, inside that component am having two elements icons and text, so , when i run test for text then it is working fine, and not working for that icons.
**Component file:- **
import { faCircleInfo } from "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { tailwind } from "../../utils/tailwind";

export interface FieldErrorMessageProps {
  message?: string;
}

const FieldErrorMessage: React.FC<FieldErrorMessageProps> = ({ message }) => {
  if (!message) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={tailwind("flex-row", "items-center", "mt-1")}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={faCircleInfo}
        size={14}
        style={tailwind("text-primary-coral")}
        testID="field-error-icon"
      />
      <View style={tailwind("flex-shrink")}>
        <Text
          testID="field-error-message"
          style={tailwind(
            "font-inter-medium",
            "text-primary-coral",
            "text-sm",
            "ml-2"
          )}
        >
          {message}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FieldErrorMessage;

Test file
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import { View as MockView } from "react-native";
import FieldErrorMessage from "../FieldErrorMessage";

jest.mock("@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome", () => ({
  FontAwesomeIcon: jest.fn((props) => <MockView {...props} />),
}));

describe("FieldErrorMessage", () => {
  test("renders nothing if message is null or undefined", () => {
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<FieldErrorMessage />);
    expect(queryByTestId("field-error-message")).toBeNull();
    expect(queryByTestId("field-error-icon")).toBeNull();
  });

  test("renders the icon and message correctly when the message is updated", () => {
    const message = "This is an error message";
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<FieldErrorMessage message={message} />);
    expect(queryByTestId("field-error-message")).toBeTruthy();
    expect(queryByTestId("field-error-icon")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

The second test for the FieldErrorMessage component fails to find the icon by its testID. Despite various methods to locate the element, it remains unsuccessful. The issue likely lies in the mocked FontAwesomeIcon component or the test environment setup. Ensure the mock implementation correctly renders the element with the provided testID

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome/issues/142

@Phil there is no different selector except testID
